# Entity Framework how to force table-per-hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 with the following Model simplified:

[image]

On creation I set everything up in the Table Mapping. For example that GlobalScope Maps to Scopes. But when I hit "Generate Database from Model" it's doing the table per type way, getting two Tables, what I dont want. So how can I force it to use table per hierarchy?

[image]

Comment: have you read [these articles](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) ?

Comment: Did you set the `Scope` model as `Abstract` in the diagram ?

Comment: Yes, Scope is Abstract.

Comment: Could be the Problem that UniqueID is not nullable?